# RequestValidationError: JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray (type=type_error.json)

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I've got an endpoint in my FastAPI application for receiving form data:

```py
@router.post("/foobar")
async def handler(
    form_data: Bar = Depends(Bar.as_form),
) -> JSONResponse:
    ...
```

What I'm trying to do is to validate form data with help of `pydantic`. Here are the models:

```py
from fastapi import Form
from pydantic import BaseModel, Json


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str


class Bar(BaseModel):
    any_field: Optional[List[Foo]]

    @classmethod
    def as_form(
        cls,
        any_field: Json[List[Foo]] = Form(None, media_type="application/json"),
    ) -> "Bar":
        return cls(any_field=any_field)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
fastapi.exceptions.RequestValidationError: 1 validation error for Request
body -> any_field
  JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray (type=type_error.json)
```

I've added exception handler for `RequestValidationError` to make sure that `any_field` is actually `str` type:

```py
@application.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    body: FormData = exc.body

    return JSONResponse(
        content={"msg": str([type(v) for v in body.values()])},
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
    )
```

Here is my request:
[image]

As you may see, it is `str`.

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

You could let FastAPI do the validation on its own. For example...

```py
from fastapi  import FastAPI, Form, File, UploadFile
from pydantic import BaseModel, Json
from typing   import Optional, List

class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: str

class Bar(BaseModel):
    any_field: Optional[List[Foo]] = Form()

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/foobar")
async def handler(upload: UploadFile = File(), form_data: Json[Bar] = Form()):
    return {'form_data': form_data, 'upload': upload.filename}
```

Here is code illustrating use of the endpoint...

```py
import requests
import json

reqUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobar"

with open("/Users/pelletier/Playground/scores.csv", "rb") as upload:
    post_files = {'upload': upload}
    payload    = {'form_data': json.dumps({'any_field': [{'a': 'foo'}, {'a': 'foo'}]})}
    response   = requests.post(reqUrl, data=payload, files=post_files)
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know about this, but I want to send request with `multipart/form-data` content type. So, I need to validate data that way

Comment: I've updated the answer to illustrate processing of multipart/form-data